# The value of the property 'addEvent' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, moodle, curvycorners

I am trying to add rounded borders in IE7 and 8 in a theme for Moodle and I am using JavaScript curvycorners.js script to do so. I've added the following code in my script:-

```
<html <?php echo $OUTPUT->htmlattributes() ?>>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $PAGE->title ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('favicon', 'theme')?>" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php p(strip_tags(format_text($SITE->summary, FORMAT_HTML))) ?>" />
    <?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_head_html() ?>
    <script src="/curvycorners.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
addEvent(window, 'load', initCorners);
function initCorners() {
var setting = {
tl: { radius: 10 },
tr: { radius: 10 },
antiAlias: true
}
curvyCorners(setting, ".navbar");
curvyCorners(setting, ".minicalendar");
curvyCorners(setting, ".block-region .block .header");
curvyCorners(setting, ".coursebox");
curvyCorners(setting, "#news_header");
}
</script>
```

However, in IE7 I am getting an error:-
The value of the property 'addEvent' is null or undefined, not a Function object when trying to run the script.

Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about `attachEvent` (IE/Opera) or `addEventListener`(Chrome/Safari/Firefox):

```
attachEvent(window, 'onload', initCorners);     // IE/Opera
addEventListener(window, 'load', initCorners);  // Chrome/Firefox/Safari
```

Comment: I was following the example as shown in http://www.thesimplexdesign.com/2009/11/make-rounded-corners-for-web-elements.html. I tried with attachEvent also but I get another error SCRIPT5: Type mismatch.

Comment: Are you sure that curvycorners.js is loaded?

Comment: Try to save your page os JSFiddle.net